# Stanford OpenIE Example Code would not run properly

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

this is my first time here posting something; so if I have demonstrated any bad practice- please tell.

So currently I am trying to use OpenIE from Stanford to extract information from web-mined data. As I am really new to Java, I just copied the example code snippet from their page: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml

Which looks like this:

```
  import java.util.*;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.NaturalLogicAnnotations;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
  import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    Annotation doc = new Annotation("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");
    pipeline.annotate(doc);

    for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
      for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
        System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
            triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.objectLemmaGloss());
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I compiled it into a class and put it into the openIE jar from their site.

I ran such a command, which is nearly identical to their command-line invocation example:

```
java -mx1g -cp stanford-openie.jar:stanford-openie-models.jar Example
```

But in the end I got such an error:

```
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as either class path, filename or URL
```

While their command line invocation would work as shown on their page, I think this is a problem with my Java skills. However I couldn't figure out how to fix this, nor the relevant questions asked on Stackoverflow would help. Why cannot it resolve the classpath?

*Note:* I saw somebody posting about having CoreNLP in their workspace at the same time, but I am sure I am NOT putting those JARs together under the same directory.

Comment: The error is caused by the code trying to load the constituency parser, rather than the dependency parser model. Can you paste your Example.java file exactly as it appears? This error should not occur if you do not have "parse" in your list of annotators.

Answer (score 2):

Change the setProperty line to the following. I was facing the same issue. A change in this line made it work.

Also, you should include the CoreNLP and the Openie jars in the path to help it work properly.

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
```